# Why is $K[\alpha]$ a polynomial ring and the smallest subring containing $K$ and $\alpha$ of $L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. 
Why is $$K[\alpha]:=\{ \sum^d_{i=0}c_i\alpha^i:c_i\in K:0\leq i\leq d\}=\bigcap_{K\subset M \subset L; \alpha \in M \text{ ring}} M$$
Reading lecture notes on galois theory one defines $K[T]$ as polynomial ring. Later $K[A]$ is defined as the smallest subring containing set $A\subset L$ and $K$.
In particular if $A=\{\alpha\}$ notations above do overlap. But for me it is not obvious that they are equal and it is not really explained in the notes.

Comment: Any ring containing $\alpha$ and $K$ will contain all powers $\alpha^n$ for $n=0,1,...$ and products of those with elements of $K$ and sum of those. Therefore, $K[\alpha]\subset M$ for $M$ in that $\bigcap$. Also $K[\alpha]$ is a ring containing $K$ and $\alpha$. Therefore $K[\alpha]$ is one of the terms in the intersection.

Comment: @yixing That's an answer. Why are you leaving it in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur To give you a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $K[t]$ can mean different things depending on the context.

If $K$ is any field and $t$ is an indeterminate, then $K[t]$ is the polynomial ring over $K$ in one variable, in other words, the free commutative $K$-algebra on one generator.

If $K\subset L$ is a field extension and $t$ is an element of $L$, then $K[t]$ denotes the $K$-subalgebra of $L$ generated by $t$. In general, this is not a free algebra, since $t$ might satisfy polynomial relations. For example, when $K=\mathbb R$, $L=\mathbb C$ and $t=i$, we have
$$
\mathbb R[i] = \mathbb C \cong \mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle,
$$
where $\mathbb R[i]$ denotes the subalgebra generated by $i$, $\mathbb R[x]$ denotes the polynomial ring (or free algebra) and the isomorphism is given by $i\mapsto x$, since $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $i$ in the extension $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$.

Note that still
$$
K[t] = \left\{\, \sum_{i=0}^d c_i t^i \,\middle|\, c_i\in K, d\in\mathbb N\right\}
$$
is true in **both** settings.

Comment: In the case of field extensions, it would be worthwhile to remark that if $K(t)$ denotes the subfield of $L$ generated by $t$ (which is also the field of fractions of $K[t]$), then actually $K(t)=K[t]$, because $K[t]\cong K[X]/(P(X))$, where $P(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K$, and the irreducibility (by definition) of $P(X)$ implies that $K[X]/(P(X))$ is a field.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $t$ above is supposed to be algebraic over $K$. If $t$ is transcendental over $K$, then of course $K[t]\cong K[X]$.